# Alert notification for unauthorized users

Tags: debian, ssh, putty

[image][image]
Hi I'm using a Phidgets SBC (Single Board Computer ) connected to my PC. So I would like to create an Alert Notification so that whoever enters the Phidgets SBC, triggers an alert notification to the Main User. I'm not sure how to do it, I've searched and there is only results about Email notification. However the PC and Phidgets SBC are not connected to the internet, so I don't think email notification is possible, I was thinking if it could show a pop up banner with alert. Is it possible? I'm using Putty for SSH.

Comment: They are not connected to the internet, but locally connected by wire? How would anyone enter the SBC without you noticing, if you're sitting there looking at the pop up banner alert?

Comment: `pam_exec` can be used to run a notification script on every login. Where should the notification pop up?

Comment: So you want a banner to appear on your computer? What OS is your computer running? How would people connect to the SBC?

Comment: @grebneke i've connected both of them to a router , please see the attached picture .

Comment: @terdon yup , Debian Linux . Wirelessly through the router  , they will see it in the connection list , please see attached picture

Comment: @jofel i was thinking it should pop out on the computer screen of the user or at the Putty (SSH) command browser

Comment: You can use the `write` or `wall` command to send notifications to terminals.

Comment: any sample codes ? @jofel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pam_exec` and `wall` to send a notification to every terminal
on each login.

Here a example from http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html modified for your purpose (not tested):

Create a script `/usr/local/bin/notify-login` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$PAM_TYPE" = "open_session" ] || exit 0
{
  echo "Login User: $PAM_USER"
  echo "Ruser: $PAM_RUSER"
  echo "Rhost: $PAM_RHOST"
  echo "Service: $PAM_SERVICE"
  echo "TTY: $PAM_TTY"
  echo "Date: `date`"
} | wall -n
```

and add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/notify-login
```